# Do I need celery when I am using gevent?

Tags: python, django, celery, gevent

I am working on a django web app that has functions (say for e.g. sync_files()) that take a long time to return. When I use gevent, my app does not block when sync_file() runs and other clients can connect and interact with the webapp just fine.

My goal is to have the webapp responsive to other clients and not block. I do not expect a zillion users to connect to my webapp (perhaps max 20 connections), and I do not want to set this up to become the next twitter. My app is running on a vps, so I need something light weight.

So in my case listed above, is it redundant to use celery when I am using gevent? Is there a specific advantage to using celery? I prefer not to use celery since it is yet another service that will be running on my machine.

edit: found out that celery can run the worker pool on gevent. I think I am a litle more unsure about the relationship between gevent & celery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short you do need a celery.

Even if you use gevent and have concurrency, the problem becomes request timeout. Lets say your task takes 10 minutes to run however the typical request timeout is about up to a minute. So what will happen if you trigger the task directly within a view is that the server will start processing it however after a minute a client (browser) will probably disconnect the connection since it will think the server is offline. As a result, your data can become corrupt since you cannot be guaranteed what will happen when connection will close. Celery solves this because it will trigger a background process which will process the task independent of the view. So the user will get the view response right away and at the same time the server will start processing the task. That is a correct pattern to handle any scenarios which require lots of processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am currently using RQ from python-rq.org for queuing... Am I correct in thinking that celery & RQ perform similar functions (without going into architectural differences)? I should have added the note about RQ in my question - sorry.